# hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true breaking integration tests with H2 in-memory DB. Table not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

Due to upgrading to MySQL version 8.0, some of my tables have names which are now reserved words. As a result, I have added the property `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true`. This has solved the issue but it has broken my integration tests which use H2 as an in-memory DB.
I am using Hibernate to persist the JPA entities and Spring's `TestEntityManager` to manage the interactions with the database during the tests.
The error I am getting is

```
2020-10-08 10:08:38  WARN [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper]: SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2020-10-08 10:08:38  ERROR [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper]: Table "CALCULATION" not found; 
SQL statement: insert into `calculation` (.....)
```

Thie is my H2 url: `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=true;`

I have tried adding `;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` to the url.

Here is a snippet of my JPA entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calculation")
public class Calculation extends BaseEntity<Long> implements Serializable
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. This may not work for everyone but I had to add
`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true`.
Posting this in case it will help someone else.

Comment: I found `hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true` is what I needed. Basically, H2 did not like quoting of table names, so `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` would break everything, but the `auto_quote_keyword` was effective.